# How to run javascript code when the value of a selected item changes

Tags: javascript

```js
function hidenv() {

  var txt = document.querySelector(".wapf-grand-total")[0].innerText;
  if (txt === "$260") {document.querySelector("button").style.display = "none";
  }
        
}
hidenv();
```

```html
<input class="wapf-grand-total">
<button>button</button>
```

I want to hide/show the button when a element have a diferent value of $260 but with my code it only happen when i refresh the page. I need that this function run when the value change on real time but i don't know how do it.

```js
function hide() {

  var txt = document.querySelectorAll(".wapf-grand-total")[0].innerText;
  if (txt !== "$260") {document.querySelector("button").style.display = "none";
  }
        
}
hide();
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal reproducable example?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - Please take the [tour] and, as @deepakchethan mentioned, add a minimal amount of code (HTML/JS) to help you out faster - also known as [mcve]

Comment: why you are using querySelectorAll ? when you can use querySelector for first match
and can i know the type of element which you want to check for change give here that html code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can track changes in input fields with `oninput` event listener . now it will trigger your check function each time when input field is changed

```js
function hidenv() {
  var inputEl = document.querySelector(".wapf-grand-total"),
      btn = document.querySelector("button"),
      isVal260 = inputEl.value == "$260"
      btn.hidden = isVal260
}

document.querySelector(".wapf-grand-total").addEventListener("input",hidenv)

// hidden method update suggested by @connexo
```

```html
<input type="text" class="wapf-grand-total">
<button>button</button>
```

Comment: Try `btn.hidden = inputEl.value === "$260"` instead of your if..else block.

Comment: ya i think its also a good way

Comment: i forgot to mention that for all input fields you have to use `.value` to get value not innerHTML or InnerText input fields are a widget in html so they have different behaviour than other simple elements like div , p , span etc

Comment: Raman Then edit that into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use event listener .

```js
    document.querySelector('.wapf-grand-total').addEventListener('keyup', hide)
```